# CakePHP LIKE statements?

Tags: mysql, cakephp

If the field `gp_categories` contains the string '12 56 34 345 349', how can I find records that contain the number 34?

```
$id = 34;

// 1. Works but is there a more efficient way?
$q['conditions']['OR'] = array(
    array('Groups.gp_categories LIKE' => $id), // Only
    array('Groups.gp_categories LIKE' => $id.' %'), // Start
    array('Groups.gp_categories LIKE' => '% '.$id.' %'), // Middle
    array('Groups.gp_categories LIKE' => '% '.$id) // End
);

// 2. Finds either 34, 345, 349 etc
$q['conditions'] = array('Groups.gp_categories LIKE' => '%'.$id.'%');
```

Comment: Have you tried [mysql regex](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html)? Or do you want a cake solution?

Comment: I would prefer Cake solution though I guess I could fire in a custom Model query in Cake if need be, I've never used MYSQL regex function before.

Comment: That db schema looks terrible - is it deliberate? Why are you storing space delimited numbers? Can you change it to something more sane? even " 12 56 ... " would be more sensible since then you can just search for matching " number ", irrespective of whether its the only number, in the middle or last.

Comment: Looks like a candidate for some refactoring; I think a HABTM relation is more appropriate in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use regex in the database side

```
 $q['conditions'] = array("Groups.gp_categories REGEXP" => "[[:<:]]".$id."[[:>:]]");
```

(that's mysql, btw, you need to change it if you're using another db).

You could wrap that find in a model function or leave it in the controller if it's not reused somewhere else.

Example

```
public function getByCategory($id) {
    return $this->find('all', array('conditions'=> 
           array("Groups.gp_categories REGEXP" => "[[:<:]]".$id."[[:>:]]")));
}

//in controller
$this->YourModel->getByCategory($id);
```

I'm not aware if there's a more efficient function in cake, so that's a probable no. Also, you'll have to test if a regex expression in the DB is more efficient than the LIKE query you're already using, I haven't benchmarked it. But it should be more efficient than 4 likes.

Comment: Mmm throws an error 'Syntax error or access violation' i'm using MYSQL 5.5

Comment: @woodscreative Sorry about that, missed a "P" and added useless `'`... I've updated, try the new one, please

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   $gp_categories = '12 56 34 345 349' ;
    if (strpos($gp_categories,'34') !== false) {
    echo 'true';
    }
```

Comment: for that he would have to do a find('all') before and traverse the whole array

Comment: Yeh I need it to be in a query.

Answer (score 0):

```
Using Locate
```

LOCATE works like this:

```
LOCATE(<string to find>, <string to find it in>)
```

or

```
LOCATE(<string to find>, <string to find it in>, <position to start at>)
```

For example, to find the location of "oranges" in the string "apples oranges pears bananas apples oranges" do this:

```
SELECT LOCATE("oranges", "apples oranges pears bananas apples oranges");
```

This will return 8. To find the next occurance of "oranges" in the source string, pass the third parameter to the function telling it to start from position 9 in this example:

```
SELECT LOCATE("oranges", "apples oranges pears bananas apples oranges", 9);
```

This will now return 37. Note that in these examples if 8 had been passed as the starting position then 8 would have been returned.

for more use of this you can [refer link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html)

but that what you have to convert it in to cakephp array,

Comment: Wouldn't I need a current record to define the <string to find it in> to then run LOCATE? What about adding other possible clauses to this query?